# Grafana Unauthorized problem on Azure Container Apps

Tags: azure, docker, nginx, containers, grafana

I have a Grafana instance on an Azure VM and am trying to containerise and host it on Azure Container Apps. I use **grafana/grafana:7.0.0-ubuntu** and **nginx** in my docker container. The container works on my local successfully but on Azure, it throws an error **(Unauthorized)** and signs me out. After that error, the system does not allow me to sign in for like 5 to 10 mins. 10 mins later, I can sign in again but the same scenario occurs again.

Also, I have some default dashboards. If I don't view them, the error does not happen. I can view all my metrics on the board until the error happens.

**My Dockerfile;**

```
FROM grafana/grafana:7.0.0-ubuntu
EXPOSE 8080 8080
COPY nginx /nginx
COPY start-nginx.sh /start-nginx.sh
USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nginx -y
RUN chmod +x /start-nginx.sh
RUN cp /nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN grafana-cli plugins install grafana-piechart-panel 
RUN chown -R root:root /etc/grafana/provisioning
ENV GF_SECURITY_COOKIE_SAMESITE=disabled
ENV GF_SERVER_SERVE_FROM_SUB_PATH=true
ENTRYPOINT [ "/start-nginx.sh" ]
```

**Also my nginx config;**

```
worker_processes  1;
pid /var/lib/nginx/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  sendfile  on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  server {
    listen 8080;

    server_name MY_CUSTOM_DOMAIN;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    } 
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the point of using of nginx (and old Grafana version) in your case?

Comment: can you share the details of configuration files in nginx folder?

Comment: @JanGaraj I don't have a lot information about the container apps. I watched a couple of videos and tried to implement my current instance. Thanks

Comment: @GoonaBabu I shared the nginx.conf file in the post. I don't have any other configuration files after that. Thanks.